# How to change built_in module in python

Tags: python

I want to change os.path in `os.py`, but it failed. path is different in different platform.

`os.py`

```
import ntpath as path
sys.modules['os.path'] = path
from os.path import (curdir, pardir, sep, pathsep, defpath, extsep, altsep, devnull)
```

It turns out that

```
    from os.path import (curdir, pardir, sep, pathsep, defpath, extsep, altsep,
devnull)
ImportError: No module named path
```

Comment: @zetysz sorry, could you tell more? I don't understand.

Comment: os.path is not a module...

Comment: I think that `zetysz` is suggesting that you do:  `vars(os.path).update(vars(ntpath))` -- Which should replace `os.path` methods with their `nt` counterparts (or [do nothing if you're on windows. . .](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py#l63))

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. Did you name your program `os.py`?

Comment: @zetysz, just saw it,  im retrieving info, thanks for it mate :)

Comment: @MikeMüller I want to replace `os.py` modules. The new `os.py` can be portable

Comment: As @MikeMüller mentioned, is **the name** of the file you **are running** `os.py`?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @DanielSanchez - what are you talking about? `os.path` definitely is a module...

Comment: @dwanderson, better read all than reopen ended conversations mate

Comment: @DanielSanchez yeah, sorry about that, I tried following but still got confused. I don't see any comments from zetysz, so maybe that's throwing me off. Just didn't want wrong/stale info sittin around on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should work. Rename the subdirectory `os` in your current directory to `my_os`. Python finds your `os` directory first and tries to import from there.

Adding this line:

```
__future__ import absolute_import
```

to the beginning of the `os.py` avoids this problem by using [absolute imports](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/2.5.html?highlight=absolute%20import#pep-328).

Comment: I add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the beginning. it works. Interpreter will find `os.path` in sys.modules but current file.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with "[__import__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)" function ?

```
import mtpath as path
os_path = __import__(path, globals(), locals(), ['curdir', 'pardir', 'sep', 'pathsep', 'defpath', 'extsep', 'altsep', 'devnull']
```

Then, you can use 'curdir' as :

```
os_path.curdir
```

Well, you can also asign it to 'curdir' name as in the documentation :

```
curdir = os_path.curdir
pardir = os_path.curdir
…
```

Comment: but we can not use it in other files。

Comment: I want to replace `os.py` modules. The new os.py can be portable. So os.path must be replaced.